# Why shared library path is hardcoded in execuatble?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Recently I got a test binary. When I checked it using objdump, I observed that it includes hard coded library path. Why it is needed to to hardcode the path like that? Shouldn't the path be taken from SHELL environment variables or -L parameter instead ?

> objdump -p testprog

The output includes the hardcoded path to shared libraries:

```
....
  NEEDED      /home/test/lib/liba.so
  NEEDED      /home/test/lib/libb.so
  NEEDED      /home/test/lib/libc.so
....
```

Comment: Maybe that is the resolved path on your system?

Comment: Agree with RedX. Do you actually get any output when executing `strings testprog | grep /home/test`?

Comment: @NiklasB. The strings give me the all the embedded path above. It is hardcoded inside binary during the compilation.

Comment: @Lunar: What compiler do you use?

Comment: @NiklasB. I received that binary from a customer. They are using gcc (Arm gcc). I think embedding the library path is a standard feature. But I did not get why it is embedded. Also I am interested to know which compiler option caused this path to be embedded (I cannot get sources from customer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably because those three `.so` files had no SONAME on the host where your test program was built. Tell the person who built it to rebuild `liba.so` with `-Wl,soname,liba.so` and similar for the other two, then relink the main program.

Comment: Accepting answer : I got similar info from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305266/how-to-link-to-a-shared-library-without-lib-prefix-in-a-different-directory

Comment: It's probably because it wasn't linked as `-la` but rather as `/home/test/lib/libc.so`.

Comment: Apparently, you can use the [patchelf](https://www.mankier.com/1/patchelf) to set SONAME for **liba.so**.