# How to use shared library via G++?

Tags: c++, g++, shared-libraries

I have a library that named `matrix` and used in my program that named `test.cpp`.

I can generate and use *static* library successfully, but when I want to use it as a *shared* library, I receive the following error :

```
ap1019@sharifvm:~/the03-copy$ ls
matrix.cpp  matrix.h  test.cpp
ap1019@sharifvm:~/the03-copy$ g++ -c matrix.cpp
ap1019@sharifvm:~/the03-copy$ g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,matrix.so -o matrix.so matrix.o
ap1019@sharifvm:~/the03-copy$ ls
matrix.cpp  matrix.h  matrix.o  matrix.so  test.cpp
ap1019@sharifvm:~/the03-copy$ g++ test.cpp matrix.so
ap1019@sharifvm:~/the03-copy$ ./a.out
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: matrix.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ap1019@sharifvm:~/the03-copy$
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to follow the naming convention for shared libraries.You are linking in a wrong manner.

Check out following for details:

g++ -L/home/username/matrix -Wall -o test test.cpp -lmatrix

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html

Comment: Yes, they do - C++ adds to C in OOPS -  linking and other stuff is almost same

Comment: So I generate `.so` file as I generated in the question, and when I want to use it, I must to use the command that you said in your answer, right?

Comment: Check following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305266/how-to-link-to-a-shared-library-without-lib-prefix-in-a-different-directory